# How to add different Javascript in development and production wicket

Tags: javascript, wicket

I have a wicket application in which I have added the javascript files within the markup html:

```
<script src="script/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My javascript files are not placed beside my .java or .html files, they are in different location in the server as can be seen on previous script declaration.

My question is: Is it possible to add these javascript files depending on the application mode? I.E. if the application is in development mode, load one javascript file, if it is in production load this other one.

Thanks!

PS: the idea is to load "min" version on production but the extended files on development so debugging becomes posible

**NOTE**: Watching different answers here I re-state: the problem is not finding when the wicket app is in development or deployment mode, I know that, but is about how to change html markup or adding different JavaScript resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

extendig the answer of @rotsch you can do it in wicket 1.5 with :

```
@Override
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
    if(DEVELOPMENT)
        response.renderString("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"url1\"></script>");
    else
            response.renderString("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"url2\"></script>");

}
```

https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/migration-to-wicket-15.html#MigrationtoWicket1.5-RemovedHeaderContributorandfriends.

Comment: or, even cleaner, with the `renderHead` method, see [this in the migration guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/migration-to-wicket-15.html#MigrationtoWicket1.5-RemovedHeaderContributorandfriends.)

Answer (score 1):

You can find out in which mode you are with the following code:

`RuntimeConfigurationType.DEPLOYMENT.equals(getApplication().getConfigurationType())`

or

`RuntimeConfigurationType.DEVELOPMENT.equals(getApplication().getConfigurationType())`

Comment: I know that, but after knowing the type I want to add one or other JS

Answer (score 1):

I use this directory layout:

```
resources
|---JQueryResource.java
|---jquery-1.6.4.js
|---jquery-1.6.4.min.js
```

With this class:

```
public class JQueryResource {
    /**
     * Must be called in a RequestCycle.
     * 
     * @return Url for the jQuery library.
     */
    public static String getURL() {
        if (Application.get().usesDevelopmentConfig()) {
            Url url =
                    RequestCycle.get().mapUrlFor(
                            new PackageResourceReference(JQueryResource.class, "jquery-1.6.4.js"),
                            null);
            return url.toString();
        } else {
            Url url =
                    RequestCycle.get().mapUrlFor(
                            new PackageResourceReference(JQueryResource.class,
                                    "jquery-1.6.4.min.js"), null);
            return url.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I add the resource to my page.

```
@Override
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse a_response) {
    a_response.renderJavaScriptReference(JQueryResource.getURL());
}
```

Comment: Not bad although I prefer @osdamv answer since I don't have your same directory layout, my .js files are stored away from .java files so I need to reference them with an URL. If you know how to get such a URL with your method, that would be nice as well.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use pack:tag to compress all your resources: http://sourceforge.net/projects/packtag/

In your web.xml/.properties file you can specify whether to pack it or not depending on your production mode.

Answer (score 0):

I set a property in a `properties file` with I add to the path when starting the VM.

Then I do a if else similar to the PHP answer.

Comment: Not related to finding out when in development or not, I know that, I need to add some different files, in wicket